# Why can't you compare the value of two int type vairables?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, vector

I was just compiling some code while learning c++ and reached this on the compiler.

context: For this code which takes a 1 Dimensional vector v and a value n then tries finding this value n in v. If found returns the index of it and if not it returns -1.

```
int mfind(int n, const std::vector <int>& v){

int a = v.size();

for(int i=0; v[i]!=n && i<a; i++){
int index = i;
}

if(index < a){
    return index;
}
else{
    return -1;
}

}
```

Index and i are both integers and when compared in the if condition it outputs an error:

error: 'index' was not declared in this scope.

Is it that that you cannot compare the values of two integers ? if there is another reason to this error I would love to know why and how it is that you can compare the values of two different int type variables. many thanks.

I am new around here if I there is anything wrong with the post or layout etc let me know I will change it. Many thanks.

Comment: `index` is declared inside the `for()` loop. It's invisible outside of it

Comment: Thank you! makes sense now.

Comment: It would be a good idea to ident code properly.

Comment: If you want to delete the question  then click on "delete" -- don't edit it to remove the text. But there is no need to take any action

Answer (score 1):

The `index` variable is declared inside your `for` loop. It is invisible outside of that scope.

Declare the variable before the `for` loop.